# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out while loading dataframe to teradata using spark 2.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, teradata

I am trying to load dataframe in to teradata using JDBC driver, but getting below error.

jdbc version:- 16.10.00.07
cloudera version :- 5.15

invoking spark shell using below command.
 spark2-shell --jars terajdbc4.jar,tdgssconfig.jar,teradata-connector-1.4.4.jar

we are able to get schema of the table but not able to select or insert operation for all the columns of the table.

also the code that i am using can be found below.

```
val insertdf = spark.sql(query)
val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.setProperty("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
prop.setProperty("user", "xxxxxx")
prop.setProperty("password", "*******") 

val url = "jdbc:teradata://10.xxx.130.69/database=stg_database, TMODE=TERA"
val table = "test_table"
insertdf.write.mode("append").jdbc(url, table, prop)


ERROR:-

  Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2024)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2045)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2064)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2853)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:245)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:644)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:603)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:612)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.10.00.07] [Error 1277] [SQLState 08S01] Login timeout for Connection to 10.130.130.69 Tue Feb 04 02:05:21 EST 2020 socket orig=10.130.130.69 cid=44c91563 sess=0 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF$ConnectThread.run(TDNetworkIOIF.java:1242)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:95)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:70)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeIoJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:208)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorAnalyzer.analyzeIoError(ErrorAnalyzer.java:59)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.createSocketConnection(TDNetworkIOIF.java:163)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.<init>(TDNetworkIOIF.java:142)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeradataConnection.getIO(GenericTeradataConnection.java:142)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericLogonController.run(GenericLogonController.java:100)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.<init>(TDSession.java:211)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.<init>(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:36)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6ConnectionFactory.constructSQLConnection(JDK6ConnectionFactory.java:25)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:178)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:168)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.doConnect(TeraDriver.java:236)
  at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.connect(TeraDriver.java:162)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:61)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
```

Comment: Anything wrong with my steps??? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the important parts of the stack trace from the Teradata JDBC Driver:

[Error 1277] [SQLState 08S01] Login timeout for Connection to 10.130.130.69
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

This error means that the Teradata JDBC Driver was unable to connect to a database at the IP address 10.130.130.69.

Either that is the wrong IP address, or the database is not running (it is down), or the system that you are running your program on doesn't have connectivity to that IP address (prevented by firewall).

Comment: Thanks Tom, the issue was with the system . The connectivity to the ip address(10.130.130.69)  was not available.